# Highest primary key in a thousands range group

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and I'm trying to get the top 1000s value of primary keys of data that looks like this:

```
+ --------- + ----------- +
| id        | name        |
+ --------- + ----------- +
| 1000      | George      |
| 1002      | David       |
| 2000      | Jane        |
| 2003      | Mary        |
| 3123      | Steven      |
| 3222      | Marta       |
| 10001     | Chris       |
| 10091     | Nathan      |
+ --------- + ----------- +
```

And I'd like to grab the highest of the 1000s range. So my query would return something like this:

```
+ --------- + ----------- +
| id        | name        |
+ --------- + ----------- +
| 1002      | David       |
| 2003      | Mary        |
| 3222      | Marta       |
| 10091     | Nath        |
+ --------- + ----------- +
```

This is what I have and it works:

```
SET @2k:= 2000;
SET @3k:= 3000;
SET @4k:= 4000;
SET @11k:= 11000;

SELECT sub1.id,
       person.name
FROM
  (SELECT max(id) id
   FROM person
   WHERE id < @2k
   UNION 
   SELECT max(id) id
   FROM person
   WHERE id < @3k
   UNION 
   SELECT max(id) id
   FROM person
   WHERE id < @4k
   UNION 
   SELECT max(id) id
   FROM person
   WHERE id < @11k) sub1
JOIN person ON person.id = sub1.id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

And here is the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95ef8/14

Again, it works but is there a more dynamic way so that I don't have to create variables like @2k, @3k, etc. and create UNIONS? Like if the table grows to millions of ids the above would involve too much refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the highest key in each group of a thousand:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as max_per_thousand
FROM person
GROUP BY FLOOR(id/1000)
```

You can then join it with the person table to get the whole record for each ID:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person AS p
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as maxid
    FROM person
    GROUP BY FLOOR(id/1000)) AS t
ON p.id = t.maxid
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95ef8/16)

Comment: This is late but I wanted to say Thank You! :)